# How to enable 'Use in Layered Navigation' for EAV attribute?

Tags: attributes, layered-navigation, eav, enable-disable, mirasvit

[image]

The options are disabled and I would like to activate them. The module I am using is Mirasvit

Comment: what is type of that attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Config greyed out are just locked from your config.php.

You can activate it directly in the config.php, to find which is the attribute, you can open your code html inspector and check the name of the input. THen search for it in config and update it.If you totally delete it it wont be greyed out anymore neither.

More information about sharred configuration in magento doc : https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/deployment/examples/example-shared-configuration.html

Comment: i don't have an input, how can i know what name i can refer to?

Comment: Of course you have an input as you want to change his value ^^ (Use in layer navigation). Inspect that one, extract the name of the attribuyte and search for it in config. If you can't find it you can also delete the whole mirasvit block from your config to open all your config directly